# Convert csv file into dictionary, with chosen keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I'm basically trying to convert a csv file into a dictionary with my own named keys, but I'm getting Syntax Error for some reason. I'm using the latest Python btw.
Here's what the csv file looks like:

```
1|apple|0.50|60
2|orange|0.4|55
3|mango|0.6|33
```

I want to create a dictionary of this form for each fruit:

```
dictionary={
'1':{'fruit':'apple',
     'price':0.5,
     'stock':60},
'2':{...},
'3':{...},
}
```

Here's my attempt:

```
with open('fruit.csv', mode="rt", encoding="utf8") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
            for row in reader:
                product={row[0]:{'fruit'=row[1],'price'=row[2],'stock'=row[3]}}
            print(product)
```

But this doesn't seem to work :(
I'm new to Python and I'm still trying to learn.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is indeed wrong.

You're probably looking for

```
products = {}
with open("fruit.csv", mode="rt", encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
    for row in reader:
        products[row[0]] = {"fruit": row[1], "price": row[2], "stock": row[3]}
print(products)
```

Comment: Ahh yess I used = instead of :  That was a quick fix, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

While dealing with CSVs we use '=' instead of ':'. Your syntax is wrong. Try this.

```
import csv
di = {}
with open('fruit.csv', mode="rt", encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        di[row[0]] = {'fruit':row[1],'price':row[2],'stock':row[3]}
print(di)
```

Comment: Yes I've made a silly Syntax mistake. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score -1):

You should do like that

```
product = {}
for row in reader:
   product[row[0]] = {'fruit'=row[1],'price'=row[2],'stock'=row[3]}
```

Comment: Invalid syntax still. Dictionary keys and values are separated with colons.